# merge start and end each 2 lines python

Tags: python

I have a bed file like this:

```
contig1         170657  180657
contig1         180956  190956
contig1         273549  283549
contig1         284079  294079
contig2         48711   58711
contig2         59043   69043
```

Am I'm trying to get this output:

```
contig1         170657  190956
contig1         273549  294079
contig2         48711   69043
```

It's basic at each 2 lines, pick the firs column of line 1, the second column of line 1 and the third column of line 2. I tried read each 2 lines using next

```
with open("file.bed") as f:
    for line in f:
        nextline = next(f)
        print(line, nextline) #test
```

But with this little code returns:

```
 contig1    180657  180956
 contig1    283549  284079
```

Comment: Even when correcting the typo `pen` to `open` and fixing the indentation to make this code actually run, I get a different output. Please create a [mre].

Comment: what is your output? because when I tried, the code prints the second line of file (contig1    180657  180956) and the third line (contig1    283549  284079), and not the first and second lines...

Comment: When you try the code from the question, you should get no output at all, because `pen` is not defined and there is an indentation error. Please include exactly the code you have actually used in the question.

Comment: I update the question...

Answer (score 0):

Use `readline()`, `split()`, and some unpacking to parse the name/values in each line:

```
with open("file.bed") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            name1, val1, _ = f.readline().split()
            name2, _, val2 = f.readline().split()
            assert name1 == name2

        except ValueError:
            break

        print(name1, val1, val2)
```

Output:

```
contig1 170657 190956
contig1 273549 294079
contig2 48711 69043
```